# How to set stop loss using node-binance-api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, binance

I am using node-binance-api. I have placed the order using

```
let adjustLeverage = await binance.futuresLeverage(coin, 2);
let res_2 = await binance.futuresMarketSell(coin, quantity);
```

. Then after I want to set stop loss. How can I do that?

Comment: check 'Placing a STOP LOSS order' on https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-binance-api

Answer (score 0):

```
all is working, my example:

to place buy limit

ret = await binance.futuresBuy(future_profit_obj.pair, future_profit_obj.bought_coins, current_price, {
  newClientOrderId: my_order_id_market,
  timeInForce: "GTC"
});
to place stop loss market

let ret2 = await binance.futuresMarketSell(future_profit_obj.pair, future_profit_obj.bought_coins, {
  newClientOrderId: my_order_id_sl,
  type: "STOP_MARKET",
  stopPrice: future_profit_obj.stop_loss_price,
  priceProtect: true 
});
to place take profit limit

let ret3 = await binance.futuresSell(future_profit_obj.pair, future_profit_obj.bought_coins, future_profit_obj.take_profit_price, {
    newClientOrderId: my_order_id_tp,
    stopPrice: future_profit_obj.take_profit_price,
    type: "TAKE_PROFIT",
    timeInForce: "GTC",
    priceProtect: true
});
```